# Sonata ODM Admin custom set of filters

Tags: symfony, admin, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony3.x

I am trying to upgrade my sonata-admin section in project from version 2 to 3. As I understood, the system of filtering had a little bit changed. 
The section of filtering now is like below:

```
/**
 * Fields to be shown on filter forms
 *
 * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
 */
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('updated_from', 'doctrine_mongo_callback', [
            'callback' => function ($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if (!$value['value']) {
                    return;
                }

                $queryBuilder
                    ->field('updated_at')
                    ->gte(new \DateTime($value['value']));

                return true;
            }, 'label' => 'Updated at, from'])
        ->add('updated_to', 'doctrine_mongo_callback', [
            'callback' => function ($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if (!$value['value']) {
                    return;
                }

                $queryBuilder
                    ->field('updated_at')
                    ->lte(new \DateTime($value['value']));

                return true;
            }, 'label' => 'Updated at, to'])
        ->add('role', 'doctrine_mongo_choice', [], ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Role Name',
            'operator_type' => HiddenType::class,

            'field_options' => [
                'choices' => $this->getFilter('role')
            ]
        ]);
 }
```

Generally filters work, but I can not use only one filter separately.
When I am trying to filter by **"updated_from"** sonata ask me to choose other 2 filters and show me nothing. Then I choose those other 2 filters and everything work.

Can somebody help in this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation in this question, I came to decision.

When we set the second parameter at "***add***" method, sonata identify the filter type as "***DefaultFilterType***". Then Sonata assigns some default parameters to that filter. It influenced to the filter behavior. 
But if I leave second parameter as "***null***", then filter will be looking for a type of "***FieldType***" (4th parameter). Then filter become a "***ChoiceType***" in my case and it works fine.

And one more important stuff, that "***ChoiceType***" should be from **Symfony**, not from **Sonata**.